# Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality by sum of squares

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

I’m trying to solve: Prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality by writing $\|x\|^2\|y\|^2− |\langle x,y\rangle|^2$ as a sum of squares.

I’m fairly well versed in Cauchy-Schwarz and know several proofs but I’m confused what it means to be “writing $\|x\|^2\|y\|^2− |\langle x,y\rangle|^2$ as a sum of squares”.   I realize $\|x\|^2\|y\|^2− |\langle x,y \rangle|^2= (x \cdot x)(y\cdot y)-(x\cdot y)^2$, but how do I apply to prove?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently your teacher wants you to use [Lagrange's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity):

$$||a^2||\cdot||b^2|| - (a \cdot b)^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} \sum_{j = i + 1}^n (a_i b_j - a_j b_i)^2$$

which is indeed a sum of squares, thus it is positive, therefore $||a^2||\cdot||b^2|| \geqslant (a \cdot b)^2$ for all vectors $a$, $b$.

Answer (score 0):

using algebra take a funcion $f(x)=(a_1x+b_1)^2+(a_2x+b_2)^2\geq 0 $   expand and take de discriminat of cuadratic function which is $\Delta \geq 0$  because is the sum of two squares.

it's analogous using vectors

now using vectors take $ f(\lambda)=(\lambda X+Y)(\lambda X+Y)$ let cal X,Y vectors and a,b escalars expand  and take the discriminant respect $\lambda$